# how to start windows 10 edge without uac?

Tags: browser, operating-system

how can I open windows 10 edge without uac?

I used your search function and google looking for "start programs without uac" but all workarounds I found are only good for win7 or win8 or programs that are no apps from microsoft.

The only possibility I know is to switch between activated and inactivated uac but unfortunally with permanent reboots.

thanks for help
buja

Comment: It's a good question, but better asked at [superuser.com](http://superuser.com)